# When to say "I like the one in red" & when to say "I like the red one"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am not sure what "**the one in red**" means?

Why don't people say "**the red one**".

When to say "**I like the one in red**" & when to say "**I like the red one**"?

Comment: It might depend on what exactly you are trying to describe. A woman in a red dress? A car painted red? A red apple? A red flag?

Comment: Are you sure people don't say ''the red one''? [Data seems to disagree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+red+one%2C+the+one+in+red&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthe%20red%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20red%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Red%20One%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20red%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Red%20One%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Red%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthe%20one%20in%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20one%20in%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20one%20in%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20one%20in%20Red%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @M.A.R. I think Tom means "Why do people who say *the one in red* just not say *the red one*. I don't think he is implying that people don't say *the one in red*! (Otherwise he wouldn't be asking the question!!) :D

Answer (score 2):

> I like the one in red.
>   Means, I like **the person** wearing red.
>
> I like the red one.
>   Means, I like *that something* that is red.

That's how I understand those sentences. I'm not a native speaker, so maybe there's a better interpretation